# How to set a space's category by REST API?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am creating a lot of spaces by REST API and I would like to assign them a category, too. However I couldn't find the parameter to do so.

My Rest API

POST /rest/api/space

```
{"key":"LinuxSpace",
 "name":"Linux Team",
  "description": {
    "plain": {
      "value": "this Is A Test",
    }
  }
    }}
```

This will create the space but couldn't find a way to add a label to the space, couldn't find it anywere in the documentation.

[image]

[image]

I'm using Confluence  6.15.10

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.